Qt project does not open on every Windows platform
I prepared a comprehensive project in version 6.7.2 of Qt and compiled my project using the windeployqt method. This project, which I compiled on the Windows 11 operating system, can run on both Windows 11 and Windows 10 platforms.
However, it does not open on some Windows operating systems (especially newly formatted ones). Since it does not display any error message, I couldn't understand why it doesn't open.
When I scanned for missing .dll files between the computers where my Qt project opens and doesn't open using Dependency Walker, I noticed that the following DLL files were missing on the computers where the project doesn't open:
api-ms-win-core-atoms-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-comm-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-delayload-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-enclave-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-localization-private-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-normalization-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-privateprofile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-processtopology-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-psapi-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-mm-misc-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-security-base-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-service-core-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-service-management-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-service-management-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-service-private-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-service-winsvc-l1-1-0.dll
concrt140.dll
dcomp.dll
dwrite.dll
dwrite_3.dll
dwrite_6.dll
gdiplus.dll
mmdevapi.dll
msvcp140.dll
ucrtbase.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcruntime140.dll

Even though I gathered these DLL files one by one and added them to my project, it didn't work. I think these are Windows system DLL files, and I don't know how to integrate them into the operating systems. I also don't know if the issue is caused by this.
I am sure there is no error in the compilation because the application opens on most computers. I experience this problem on newly formatted Windows platforms.

Check Windows error/crash reporter. If it silently crashes before showing any UI element you should find more details on the error in the Windows error reported crash system.

Don't distribute files with your project that belong to your Windows installation!

Typically C++ apps crash on one Windows installation but not another because there is no matching Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable package installed.
The best way to ensure it's present is to include it in the installer.
I see you tagged the question with mingw. MinGW doesn't use this package by itself. However, you may have DLLs that need it. E.g., your Qt was build with MSVC.

To troubleshoot this check out why it doesn't work.
A few ways to do this (on the system where there are issues):

Debug the application (e.g. using gdb or lldb) to see why it aborts.
Check the depencency DLL files and see which ones are missing (other than the system files you listed above). To do this you can use https://www.dependencywalker.com/ for example.

